# What does optimizing fabs "for throughput rather than latency" mean?

Tags: vlsi, fabrication

In the context of a whirlwind tour of the modern VLSI design, tapeout, and fabrication flow in their *CMOS VLSI Design*, Weste and Harris write the following:

> Multiple chips are manufactured simultaneously on a single silicon wafer, typically 150–300 mm in diameter. Fabrication requires many deposition, masking, etching, and implant steps. Most fabrication plants are optimized for wafer throughput rather than latency, leading to turnaround times of up to 10 weeks.

My questions are about the very last sentence specifically:

(1) What do they mean here? Is the idea roughly that fabs use "deep" pipelines in order to improve throughput, at the cost of these pipelines being slower than a corresponding "one shot, end-to-end" process?

(2) Why is optimizing for throughput preferable economically speaking?

Comment: I worked for a time with G-squared just before it was bought up by Applied Materials. There was a lot of competition going on for getting out the first truly successful RTP (rapid thermal processing.) An RTP would have turn-around times of a couple of weeks as compared to, at the time, high throughput processes taking 3-5 mos. So it was a big deal. But they can only process one wafer at a time. Very expensive. So you have to want the short turn-around, badly. The high throughput processes use *boats* with many wafers in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general throughput maximises the number of parts you can make, so in turn revenue for the fab.

Latency is how long it takes from start to end of manufacturing a given part, which gives a minimum lead time for non-stocked parts.  This is normally a issue for the customer not the fab.

Most fabs therefore focus on throughput.

In terms of why favouring throughput increases latency, you want all you kit running at full capacity. You do this by having multiple pieces of kit each optimized for a given step, and deep input queues for each piece of kit, so delays on one step don't feed through to the next. This queuing adds significantly to the end-to-end delay.

Comment: This was everything I needed, thank you so much! If possible, can you specify what you mean by "kit"? Does that mean "individual wafers" or "process tools"?

Comment: Process tools was what I meant by kit.